# Subsetting on NA

Tags: r

I am trying to subset on NA for a field. I have read some other solutions online for subsetting on NA's but haven't had success. Below is a summary of the field I am trying to subset on. You can see there are 297,895 NA's.

```
summary(mc_masterc[,7])
     12      24      36      48      60      72      84      96     108     
  3220459 1276362  338254  190636  114982   73042   48081   32001   20310   
  120     132      144    <NA> 
13565    7655     3700  297895
```

When I subset using is.na, I get a dataframe with 0 observations. I have tried defining this field as numeric and as a factor. I get the same result. The only way I have gotten this to work is by giving the NA's a numeric value. I'm guessing I'm missing something easy here, but I haven't figured it out.

```
  df <-  mc_masterc[is.na(mc_masterc[,7]),]
  df

<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Update:
Thanks for the feedback. Below is some additional info:

```
str(mc_masterc[,7])
 Factor w/ 13 levels "12","24","36",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I also tried this with mc_master[,7] as numeric and got the same result. I also tried the following three and continue to be zero rows.

```
df <-  mc_masterc[mc_masterc[,7]=="NA",]
df <-  mc_masterc[mc_masterc[,7]=="<NA>",]
df <-  mc_masterc[mc_masterc[,7]=="",]

levels(mc_masterc[,7])
[1] "12"  "24"  "36"  "48"  "60"  "72"  "84"  "96"  "108" "120" "132" "144" NA   

class(mc_masterc) [1] "data.frame"
```

Comment: The behavior is strange. Can you please check `class` of `mc_masterc` and let me know?

Comment: Do a `str(mc_masterc)` which should tell you what that column actually is

Comment: Look at answer provided by me and @42-. I think that will help you to solve your problem. Even I have added a dataset which resembles your problem.

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback. I edited my original post to include the additional requested info. I still have not been able to solve this.

Comment: @DPM Thanks for additional information. It helped me to reach to additional conclusions. I have modified my answer. Hope it will help you to recover from problem.

Comment: @MKR Thank you. Converting to character worked. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @DPM I'm happy it worked for you. I think information added by you were good enough to reach conclusion and pin-point reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that there is no NA in your data.frame. Actually there is a factor `(level)` of the name `NA`. A `NA` (missing) values can be converted in to an extra `level` using function `addNA`. Once `NA` is converted in an extra level then it is no longer a `NA`. Hence `is.na()` will not work. In fact no comparison can be performed on that value.

The help in `RStudio` suggessts:

> addNA modifies a factor by turning NA into an extra level (so that NA
>   values are counted in tables, for instance).

How to subset in such cases? The simple way is to 1st convert to `as.character` and then check `is.na`.

Hence, solution could be:

```
mc_masterc[is.na(as.character(mc_masterc[,7])),]
```

**Earlier answer before updates from OP:**

One can try something like:

```
mc_masterc[(mc_masterc[,7]) == "NA",]
```

An example from a test data which resembles OP's data set:

```
> x[x[,3]=="NA",]
#   a  b  c
#1  3 10 NA
#3 11  4 NA
#4 18  8 NA

> summary(x[,3])
# 3  4 NA 
# 1  1  3 

x
#   a  b  c
#1  3 10 NA
#2 12  1  3
#3 11  4 NA
#4 18  8 NA
#5 14  6  4

str(x)
#'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ a: int  3 12 11 18 14
# $ b: int  10 1 4 8 6
# $ c: Factor w/ 3 levels "3","4","NA": 3 1 3 3 2
```

Comment: Doubtful. R would not add the flanking angle brackets to the output.

Comment: @42- You know the summary report suggest OP got a factor named as `NA`. Otherwise for actual `NA` the summary reports as `NA's`

Comment: @42- I have added an example in my answer. The 3rd column is `factor` type. `NA` is a factor. I'll add summary as well.

Comment: Arrgh. The output had "<NA>", not "NA".

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I suspect is happening. My guess is that the number 7 column is really a factor variable one of whose levels is "".

```
test <- data.frame(one = c(2,4,6,'<NA>'), two=letters[1:4])
> test[is.na(test$one) ,]
[1] one two
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

> test[test$one == "NA" ,]
[1] one two
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> test[test$one == "<NA>" ,]
   one two
4 <NA>   d

 table(test$one)

<NA>    2    4    6 
   1    1    1    1
```

Comment: Sorry. Mate. I was just a bit ahead of you in our guess. I'm sure it had added a NA as factor.

Comment: Well, I do agree that there was probably a character value that had the letters "NA" in a factor, but I don't think the flanking angle brackets would have gotten added by `summary` if its spelling was exactly "NA"..